# Why does my SendMessage call fail when the target application executes in the background?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to send text to 2 different textboxes in a 3rd party application.
And my code works. Although it doesn't work if my application executes in the background. Only if the program I send the text to is behind mine.

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: We might be able to help if you supplied some details. You can see your code. You can inspect error codes. We cannot. It's no fun for us trying to guess this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use PostMessage not SendMessage - SendMessage waits for the message to be processed by the called winproc before it returns where PostMessage places the message on the application queue and returns immediately.